# How to display k2 extrafields just beside the image of k2 item

Tags: joomla, joomla-k2

I working on a politics site, am Using K2 modules, The extra fields of the politicians are being displayed at the bottom of the K2 Item, but My requirement is to display all the available extra fields just beside the item's image.

can any one help me out, 
thanks and regards,
k2 navy user

Comment: have you tried anything yourself so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple template override is all you need to accomplish this. Make a copy of this file -

```
/components/com_k2/templates/default/item.php
```

Make all the changes you want to the copy, then upload it here -

```
/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_k2/OVERRIDE NAME/item.php
```

Once you have done that, all you need to do is to assign this new template override to the category that you want to display the content this way. In the K2 admin, in the Categories Manager, select the category, then you should see what ever OVERRIDE NAME you used in the Select a Template option.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend... it helped me a lot in various pats of the project